# How to check whether if you have a new line after getline()?

Tags: c, getline

I am thinking is that possible to check if you have a new line after `scanf` something? Because `getline()` is a function to read your input line by line. If I want to input something, then without pressing "return" on keyboard. I press <kbd>control D</kbd> <kbd>control D</kbd> instead. How should I know I don't have a new line after input something?

Comment: `if ((*lineptr)[strlen(*lineptr)-1] == '\n') { /* yes, there is a newline */` }

Comment: @kaylum I think *lineptr is a integer, you can't use strlen

Comment: Why do you think that? From the [getline man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline): `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr,..)`. That is, `*lineptr` is of type `char *`.

Comment: @kaylum I use getline(&lineptr, &len, stdin) that I initialize char *lineptr= NULL; size_t len = 0; SO here my lineptr is a address of lineptr

Comment: Exactly. And `getline` will store a string into `*lineptr`. So where do you think the integer comes from? Even if you input a number, `getline` will store that as a string not an integer. `getline` does not parse or convert the string data (unlike `scanf` for example). It seems you have some misunderstanding about how `getline` works.

Comment: @kaylum When I compile this, I got a warning: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: Well, what did you declare `lineptr` to be? It has to be a `char *`  (or equivalent `char []`) otherwise your declaration is incorrect. Please show the exact code as a [mcve] if you want help with that. It's not productive to discuss code that we can't see.

Comment: @kaylum I declare it char *lineptr= NULL..so I am just confusing that does strlen[] also works for char *?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that lineptr as shown for getline is supposed to be `char **`. What you have is not a lineptr (as defined by `getline`) but a line. So for your case do `strlen(lineptr)`.

Comment: @kaylum You are right. Thank you so much! And could you please tell me why should put two stars here. One star means dereference, my friend told me I can just view it as a string and "&" means address of which is a address and can be viewed as an integer. How about char ** - point point to ..that makes me confusing about where it is point to...

Comment: @kaylum Consider the effect of `(*lineptr)[strlen(*lineptr)-1]` if the first character is the null character.  `getline()` does not stop reading when it reads a null character, it stops reading when a `'\n'` is read.  `(*lineptr)[strlen(*lineptr)-1]` is exploitable code by a hacker.